# Create CSR using existing private key

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate

What I am trying to do is, create a CSR and with a private key that is password protected (the key).

In OpenSSL I can create a private key with a password like so:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out privkey.pem 2048
```

Is there some way I can use the key I just created and generate a CSR using the key?

If not is there some way I can generate a CSR along with a PASSWORD PROTECTED private key?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

This is the second example from [the documentation of OpenSSL req](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-req.html#EXAMPLES):

> Create a private key and then generate a certificate request from it:
>
> ```
> openssl genrsa -out key.pem 2048
> openssl req -new -key key.pem -out req.pem
> ```

Note that, if you do this directly with `req` (see 3rd example), if you don't use the `-nodes` option, your private key will also be encrypted:

> ```
> openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out req.pem
> ```

(Despite what the documentation says, it's not exactly the same as the second example, since it doesn't use `-des3`, but you would have done so anyway.)

Comment: '''openssl req -new -key key.pem -out req.pem''' is quite useful when you're renewing your certificate.

Comment: To help me keep things straight I use the following naming convention: `<domain.net>.key`, `<domain.net>.csr` and `<domain.net-foo-issuer>.crt` and `<domain.net-foo-issuer>.pem` extension for chains and such which I adopted from [The Most Common OpenSSL Commands](http://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-openssl-commands.html).

Comment: As @DanielSokolowski pointed out, although the OpenSSL documentation I quoted uses 1024-bit keys, it's certainly worth using larger keys nowadays (e.g. 2048 or above).

Answer (score 4):

A password protected key means the private key was encrypted. Herein, 'key' refers to private keys. When using a key, like when creating a certificate signing request (CSR), if the key was encrypted expect to be prompted for the password.

Create a CSR from **an existing encrypted private** `-key`. After the password prompt, depending on the openssl [configuration file](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man5/), you may be prompted to specify the distinguished name (DN) of the future certificate. Option `-new` refers to the CSR:

```
    openssl req -key a.key -new -out a.csr
```

It should be stated that creating a CSR from an existing key is not typical. Key creation is easy and low cost, and newer keys may be more secure. So the usual scenario when creating a CSR is to create a new private key.

**Update** for openssl version 3.0 (circa 2022)

genrsa was deprecated; replaced by [genpkey](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man1/openssl-genpkey.html). Also, encryption with AES128 was preferable to 3DES, for both security and performance. To create a new `-aes-128-cbc` encrypted key:
:

```
    openssl genpkey -aes-128-cbc -algorithm RSA -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048 -out a.key
```

Then, as above, use it to create a new CSR.

Or in one step, create a new 3DES encrypted RSA key + CSR:

```
    openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout a.key -out a.csr
```

Confirm what was created by the above commands. Configuration file(s) may have played a role in the commands, because not all options were used on the command line.

```
    openssl rsa -in a.key -text -noout          # key bits & primes used, prompts if encrypted
    openssl asn1parse -in a.key -i -dlimit 16   # encryption cipher used
    openssl req -in a.csr -text -noout -verify  # subject, pub key & signature algorithms, V3 extensions
```