# Use Client Cert and TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 cipher suite

Tags: ruby, openssl

**Update:**  Many of my problems just had to do with not knowing how to post the client certificate.  I've placed those [details over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30132439/how-to-use-a-client-certificate-with-http).

I am using Ruby to connect to an SSL server that only supports the **`TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256`** cipher. I also need to supply a client certificate.

When I look at the available ciphers from `OpenSSL::Cipher.ciphers`, **`TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256`** is not listed as an option.

How can I add this cipher to the available ciphers?

Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  http.use_ssl = true
  http.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read("my.cer"))
  http.ca_file = 'their_root.cer'
  http.ciphers = ['AES256-SHA256']
  http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
  http.ssl_version = :SSLv23
  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
  request.body = my_xml
  response = http.request(request)
```

The error I receive:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read finished A: sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

Inspecting the packets shows the server terminates with the message "Handshake Failure (40)" which appears to be a cipher problem.

I am not connecting from the command line, but here are the results of openssl s_client:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect dir-staging.surescripts.net:443 -tls1 -servername dir-staging.surescripts.net
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 /C=US/O=Surescripts LLC./OU=Surescripts Certification Authorities/CN=Surescripts Root Certification Authority
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
verify return:0
14089:error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-52.20.2/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1145:SSL alert number 40
14089:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_BYTES:ssl handshake failure:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-52.20.2/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:566:
```

Comment: I am trying to connect to an existing private service and just can't seem to get the SSL configured to make it work.

Comment: Edited my answer , but it's really 2 questions now.

Comment: @steenslag I can't figure out if the problem is the cipher or something else.  jww pointed out some issues with openssl command line, but no joy yet.

Comment: @Tom - related to *`http.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read("my.cer"))`*... Where are you setting the key to use with the certificate? I think you need a `http.key` in there somewhere....

Comment: @jww Where would that come from?  The key file I used to create the CSR?

Comment: @Tom - when you created your CSR, you needed a key. Do you recall what you did with the key used for the CSR? You *might* be able to find it *if* its in PEM format with `cd <working dir>; grep -R "-----BEGIN" *`. The `-----BEGIN XXX----` is the preamble for PEM encoded stuff. Also see [Create CSR using existing private key](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9471380/608639).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [openssl](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ciphers.html), this is also called "AES256-SHA256". According to [Ruby lang](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2014/10/27/changing-default-settings-of-ext-openssl/), AES256-SHA256 is considered insecure and therefor disabled. The link contains a "patch" to re-enable the insecure ciphers.

You may want to seek advise from a security pro about the risks involved for your organisation.

(Edit) The error "self signed certificate in certificate chain" needs to be [taken care](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/SOURCETREEKB/Resolving+SSL+Self-Signed+Certificate+Errors) of.

Comment: I know you're just the messenger, but... There's nothing wrong with AES256-SHA256. POODLE was a CSRF against user agents like the browser. (Browsers are notoriously insecure due to their security model and design principles). Other user agents were *not* susceptible. You can find a good discussion about it on the TKS Working Group's [Rethink TLS 1.3](https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/tls/current/msg14704.html). And Ruby enables RC4, which we know is weak and wounded. It looks like more Ruby security bugs to me.

Answer (score 0):

> When I look at the available ciphers from `OpenSSL::Cipher.ciphers`, `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256` is not listed as an option.

The following OpenSSL command will list the relevant ciphers for you:

```
$ openssl ciphers -v 'ALL:!RC4:!MD5:!aNULL' | grep AES256 | grep SHA256`.
```

The results are:

```
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
DH-RSA-AES256-SHA256    TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
DH-DSS-AES256-SHA256    TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
AES256-SHA256           TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
```

Based on [Is it possible to enable TLS v1.2 in Ruby? If so, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11059059/608639), you should next try to change the following:

```ruby
http.ssl_version = :SSLv23
```

To:

```ruby
ctx = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
ctx.ssl_version = :TLSv1_2
```

---

> How can I add this cipher to the available ciphers?

Based on the *Edit* to your question:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect dir-staging.surescripts.net:443 -tls1 -servername dir-staging.surescripts.net

14089:error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-52.20.2/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1145:SSL alert number 40
14089:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_BYTES:ssl handshake failure:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-52.20.2/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:566:
```

OpenSSL 0.9.8 does *not* support TLS 1.2. You should move to OpenSSL 1.0.0 or above. OpenSSL 1.0.2 is the latest, and you are encouraged to use it.

Comment: I upgraded openssl and re-ran that command: https://gist.github.com/tomrossi7/030f95513390edce3042  I also updated my code: https://gist.github.com/tomrossi7/3c8d564fedfd22249b3c.  Still can't get it to go through

Comment: Check out those gists.  Unfortunately I don't have control over that server and it is locked down by IP.

Comment: @Tom - it looks like a problem related to the server or its configuration. You are able to connect, perform key exchange and then arrive at a master key. Then, you inexplicably get an alert 40. Do they want a client certificate?

Comment: yes, they want a client certificate.  How can I pass it with the openssl command?  You can see it in my ruby code.

Comment: @Tom -Damn, I missed that .... Sorry about that. For `s_client`, try the `-cert` option to pass the cert. You will also want `-key` option (and `-certfom` and `-keyform`). Here's the [manpage on `s_client`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/s_client.html).

Comment: Gotcha.  I added the cert and key (both in PEM).  Now when I run it https://gist.github.com/tomrossi7/030f95513390edce3042.  Is the connection working?

Comment: it looks like that was what was missing.  The alert 40 sent me down a rabbit hole, but you helped a ton.  Thanks!

Comment: @Tom - Yes, that's correct. If interested, you can clear *"Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)"* with the `-CAfile` option to `s_client`. But that's usually a trivial detail. When you get to that point, you are effectively done trouble shooting.