# How to use a client certificate with HTTPS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do you provide all the details necessary to make an HTTPS request with an SSL client certificate?

Comment: This might make a good FAQ because Ruby docs and examples sux at times. I avoid Ruby altogether because as a beginner who has read the book, I can't figure out how to get basic security services to work. Unfortunately, I don't know how to mark it as a FAQ item.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, so I looked all over and found bits and pieces of what I needed.  I want to provide this for anyone else that is struggling.  All of the files were put in a PEM format.  I used the `client.key` file to create a CSR that was given to the server administrator.  In return I got a P7B file that I then needed to be convert into PEM files.  The `root.cer` and `client.cer` file came from the P7b.

```
  uri = URI.parse(my_url_stril)
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  http.use_ssl = true
  http.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read("client.cer"))
  http.ca_file = 'root.cer'
  http.key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read("client.key"))
  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
  request.body = body
  response = http.request(request)
```

Let me know if you need more details!

Comment: Wow, that was a fast answer... Almost as though you asked the question just so that you could answer it. :)

Comment: @DavidHoelzer I did!  They were posted at the same time.

Comment: @jww 2 breakthroughs I needed. The parsing of the p7b (needed a PC to do it) and you asked me about the .key file. Once I got the client.cert out of the p7b and loaded the .key file, everything worked!  I didn't even need to do anything with the cipher.  Thank you so much!!  Can you DM me somehow?

Comment: @TomRossi I think I stumbled on the same problem. Only question I'm still having is how did you managed to extract the client.key and root.cer form the p7b file.